# Trying to understand function and callback scope by filling out objects

Tags: javascript

I have make some functions to retrieve data using the Github API. I have the callbacks in place to get the data but I am sure how to understand where a function exits and when I stops modifying things.

For example in the code below, in the first function, when the AJAX call is successful, the callback is executed in the second function where the data is manipulated. Does that mean the the return in the first function is not needed or used? And in the second function is the data used and pushed to the array and then the array returned or is it the other way around where the (empty) array is returned and then the callback does its thing.

I am ultimately trying to get the data from the callback into an object and return that filled object from the parent function.

```
function makeAJAXCall(hash, cb) {
    var returnedJSON, cb = cb, hash = hash;
    $.ajax({
        accepts: 'application/vnd.github-blob.raw',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: hash,
        success: function (json) {
            console.info(json);
            returnedJSON = json;

            // Time for callback to be executed
            if (cb) {
                cb(json);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            // an error happened, check it out.
            throw error;
        }
    });
    return returnedJSON;
}

function parseBlob(hash) {
    var objectedJSON, objectList = [], i;
    objectedJSON = makeAJAXCall(hash, function (objectedJSON) {  // no loop as only one entry
        objectList.push(objectedJSON.content);
    });
    return objectList;
}

function walkTree(hash) {
    var objectedJSON, objectList = [], i, entry;
    var hash = 'https://api.github.com/repos/myAccountName/repo/git/trees/' + hash;
    objectedJSON = makeAJAXCall(hash, function (objectedJSON) {
        for (i = 0;  i < objectedJSON.data.tree.length; i += 1) {
            entry = objectedJSON.data.tree[i];
            console.debug(entry);
            if (entry.type === 'blob') {
                if (entry.path.slice(-4) === '.svg') {     // we only want the svg images not the ignore file and README etc
                    console.info(entry.path)
                    objectList.push(parseBlob(entry.url));
                }
            } else if (entry.type === 'tree') {
                objectList.push(walkTree(entry.sha));
            }
        }

    });
    console.info(objectList);
    return objectList;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var objects = walkTree('master', function () {     // master to start at the top and work our way down
        console.info(objects);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are making an `AJAX` call `A` refers to asynchronous, ie your success/error callback will be executed asynchronously.

makeAJAXCall will return before executing success/error of $ajax.

so the `objectedJSON = makeAJAXCall` will return you `undefined`

```
function makeAJAXCall(hash, cb) {
    $.ajax({
        accepts: 'application/vnd.github-blob.raw',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: hash,
        success: function (json) {
            // this function will be executed after getting response from server 
            //ie Asynchronously
            //here cb passed from the makeAjaxCall exist in the closure scope
            if (cb) {
                cb(json);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            // an error happened, check it out.
            throw error;
        }
    });
}
```

Now when you call makeAjaxCall the callback function you are passing will exist in the closure scope of $.ajax and will be executed on success of server response

```
makeAJAXCall(hash, function (objectedJSON) {  
    //objectJSON contains the response from server
    // do all your operations using server response over here or assign it to a global variable
});
```

check below links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

https://mikewest.org/2009/05/asynchronous-execution-javascript-and-you

or you can make your ajax call in sync using `async:false` which is highly not recommended

```
function makeAJAXCall(hash, cb) {
    var returnedJSON;
    $.ajax({
        accepts: 'application/vnd.github-blob.raw',
        dataType: 'json',
        async : false, //this will make it in sync
        url: hash,
        success: function (json) {
            console.info(json);
            returnedJSON = json;
        //now makeAJAXCall will wait for success to complete and it will return only after executing success/error 
        // Time for callback to be executed
            if (cb) {
                cb(json);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            // an error happened, check it out.
            throw error;
        }
    });
    //will wait for success/error before returning
    return returnedJSON;   
}
```

In the above case your code will work

Comment: Can you point to some examples where the correct thing is done so I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeAJAXCall(hash, cb) {
    var returnedJSON, cb = cb, hash = hash;
    return $.ajax({
        accepts: 'application/vnd.github-blob.raw',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: hash,
        success: function (json) {
            console.info(json);
            returnedJSON = json;

            // Time for callback to be executed
            if (cb) {
                cb(json);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            // an error happened, check it out.
            throw error;
        }
    });

}

function parseBlob(hash) {
    var objectedJSON, objectList = [], i;
    objectedJSON = makeAJAXCall(hash, function (objectedJSON) {  // no loop as only one entry
        objectList.push(objectedJSON.content);
    });
    return objectList;
}

function walkTree(hash) {
    var objectedJSON, objectList = [], i, entry;
    var hash = 'https://api.github.com/repos/myAccountName/repo/git/trees/' + hash;
    objectedJSON = $.when(maxAJAXCall)
                    .then(function(){
                          //Write the callback  
                     });
```

Use $.when().then() to call ajax and manage the callbacks better.
[.When](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)